# Sorting a data frame column after vector for each repetition of set in data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
col1 <- 1:10
col2 <- rep(c("COL","CIP","CHL","GEN","TMP"), 2)
col3 <- rep(c("spec1", "spec2"), each = 5)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to sort the order of col2 after "order_vector", for each of the "spec" in col3. I have tried the following, but it only works for one of the "spec" as the other is removed from the data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
order_vector <- c("CHL","GEN","COL","CIP","TMP")

df <- df %>%
  slice(match(order_vector, col2))
```

This returns the following data frame:

```
col1   col2   col3
3      CHL    spec1
4      GEN    spec1
1      COL    spec1
2      CIP    spec1
5      TMP    spec1
```

However, I would like this to work for all factor values in col3, preferably with dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `col2` as factor with your `order_vector` as levels you can just sort by it.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at("col2",factor,levels=order_vector) %>%
  arrange(col3,col2) %>%
  mutate_at("col2",as.character) # if you want to go back to characters, but maybe you shouldn't

# col1 col2  col3
# 1     3  CHL spec1
# 2     4  GEN spec1
# 3     1  COL spec1
# 4     2  CIP spec1
# 5     5  TMP spec1
# 6     8  CHL spec2
# 7     9  GEN spec2
# 8     6  COL spec2
# 9     7  CIP spec2
# 10   10  TMP spec2
```

Or simpler, inspired by CPak's answer:

```
df %>% arrange(col3,factor(col2,levels=order_vector))
```

You can also use the fact that `dplyr` joins preserve order:

```
df %>%
  right_join(data.frame(col2=order_vector)) %>%
  arrange(col3)

#    col1 col2  col3
# 1     3  CHL spec1
# 2     4  GEN spec1
# 3     1  COL spec1
# 4     2  CIP spec1
# 5     5  TMP spec1
# 6     8  CHL spec2
# 7     9  GEN spec2
# 8     6  COL spec2
# 9     7  CIP spec2
# 10   10  TMP spec2
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely. Would you say this is a fast method? I don't really have a very big data frame now, but later on I might have a lot more data to try this on.

Comment: It should be fast to sort factors, and converting to factor should be quite fast as well. To optimize speed convert all your tables containing CHL etc to factors from the start and then you'll just need `df %>% arrange(col3,col2)` whenever you need it sorted. Most likely it will be fast either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forcats::fct_relevel`

```
df %>% 
   arrange(forcats::fct_relevel(col2, order_vector))

   # col1 col2  col3
# 1     3  CHL spec1
# 2     8  CHL spec2
# 3     4  GEN spec1
# 4     9  GEN spec2
# 5     1  COL spec1
# 6     6  COL spec2
# 7     2  CIP spec1
# 8     7  CIP spec2
# 9     5  TMP spec1
# 10   10  TMP spec2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option without making `col2` a factor would be to add `group_by` statement before your `match` call:

```
library(dplyr)
col1 <- 1:10
col2 <- rep(c("COL","CIP","CHL","GEN","TMP"), 2)
col3 <- rep(c("spec1", "spec2"), each = 5)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, stringsAsFactors = F)
order_vector <- c("CHL","GEN","COL","CIP","TMP")
df <- df %>%
  group_by(col3) %>% 
  slice(match(order_vector, col2))
df
```

---

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   col3 [2]
    col1 col2  col3 
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     3 CHL   spec1
 2     4 GEN   spec1
 3     1 COL   spec1
 4     2 CIP   spec1
 5     5 TMP   spec1
 6     8 CHL   spec2
 7     9 GEN   spec2
 8     6 COL   spec2
 9     7 CIP   spec2
10    10 TMP   spec2
```

Depending on how many unique values of `col3` there are or how many rows of `col2` there are to turn to a factor and back to a character vector, one or the other might be more computationally efficient, I'd imagine.

Comment: Somehow, the group_by() solution worked on the example data frame, but didn't work on my data frame, as it still only retains the first value in col3. The only difference is that there are more values in the col2 column, and some additional columns, but that shouldn't matter?